# Simple prolog function that calculates area

Tags: function, prolog

Hi I am new to prolog and I need to write a function called `rect_area(Width, Height, Area)` that can calculate the area of a rectangle, e.g.:

```
?- rect_area(2, 3, A).

A = 6.
```

Here is my try :

```
rect_area(Width, Height, Area):-
    read(Width), read(Height),
    Area is Width * Height, write(Area),nl.
```

But it doesn't work. I run it and In the listener I input

```
?- rect_area(2, 3, A).
```

no is returned.

I don't know why it is like this. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are supplying Width and Height, you don't need to `read` them.  And you might not need to print Area; it will get bound to the value and reported when rect_area finishes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to input the values of width and height and get area as return. Like if I input 
?- rect_area(10, 10, A). my expexted output is "A = 100". If I simply write this function as "rect_area(Width, Height, Area):- Area is Width * Height." The output is "no" as well. How do I fix it?

Comment: @user3221327 please show exactly what you did (edit and add it to your original post, not in a comment). If I define `rect_area(Width, Height, Area):- Area is Width * Height.` and then query, `rect_area(10, 10, A).` I get `A = 100`. Are you loading your predicate from a file or entering it in `[user]` mode?